# How to fix 'Cannot add foreign key constraint' error (string columns)

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, database-migration

I need to create foreign key between two tables. Analogically to this SQL query:

```
`alter table `katalog` add constraint `katalog_atribut_foreign` 
foreign key (`atribut`) references `polozka_sabl` (`atribut`)`
```

Error I keep getting:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General 
error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table 
`katalog` add constraint `katalog_atribut_foreign` foreign key 
(`atribut`) references `polozka_sabl` (`atribut`))
```

I tried to add 'collate' method, but nothing happened about the outcome. Still getting the error

2019_04_02_230803_create_katalog.php:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('katalog', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->string('atribut')->collate('utf8_general_ci');
            $table->string('popis');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
         Schema::table('katalog', function($table) {
            $table->primary('atribut');
            $table->foreign('atribut')->references('atribut')->on('polozka_sabl');
        });
    }
```

2019_04_02_230754_create_polozka_sabl.php:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('polozka_sabl', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigInteger('idproj')->unsigned();
            $table->string('atribut')->collate('utf8_general_ci');
            $table->primary(['idproj', 'atribut']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('polozka_sabl', function($table) {

            $table->foreign('idproj')->references('idproj')->on('projekt');
        });
    }
```

Can you help me? I tried to google but nothing really fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your first migration:

```
$table->primary('atribut');
$table->foreign('atribut')->references('atribut')->on('polozka_sabl');
```

Same column as primary and foreign key. It could be a problem. Try removing the primary key. If you really need this to be unique then you can make it unique key.

Comment: Didn't help. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced column must have an index:

```
Schema::create('polozka_sabl', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->bigInteger('idproj')->unsigned();
    $table->string('atribut')->collate('utf8_general_ci')->index();
    $table->primary(['idproj', 'atribut']);                ^^^^^^^
    $table->timestamps();
});
```